# Export Feature Layer Data from ArcGIS Online with Python

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-online, arcgis-notebook

Is it possible to export data from a feature layer in ArcGIS using either ArcPy or an ArcGIS Notebook?

I'm trying to find a way to automate exports of data collected by field workers using Field Maps to my local machine (or the local machine of other individuals in my company), preferably in a CSV, Excel, or some similar format that's easy to pull data from for reporting.
I only have an ArcGIS Online account, not an Enterprise account.

Additional clarification:
I have an ArcGIS Desktop license and I'm able to use ArcPy. My attempts so far have to find a way to use ArcPy to open, work with, and export data from my company's ArcGIS Online account have turned up nothing useful. I can't find a way to access and export the data from attribute tables in a feature layer stored in ArcGIS Online.

Comment: To use ArcPy you’ll need an ArcGIS Desktop license?  Please specify whether that’s the case and if you’re seeking Python code please include a code attempt or something to show the results of your research so far.

Comment: As a workaround I add the layers to a ArcGIS Pro project, svave the project. Read the project and [list them](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm) and copy features.

Comment: To compliment what @BERA is saying, in ArcPro, open catalog pane, then use the buttons at the top to navigate into your organisational account and add the layers directly into your map, from there you can do what ever you like.

Comment: BERA and Hornbydd, I believe this is exactly what I needed. Will test it out soon to make sure it will work for my purposes. Thank you both!